# Como substituir atributos de um JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

Tenho este `JSON` principal:

```
{
  pista: [
    {
      id: 1,
      nome: 'Himalaia',
      tipo: 'MONTANHA',
      tamanho: 30,
      debuff: -2,
      posicoesBuffs: [Array]
    }
  ],
  participantes: [
    { corredor: [Array], aliado: [Array], imimigo: [Array] },
    { corredor: [Array], aliado: [Array], imimigo: [Array] },
    { corredor: [Array], aliado: [Array], imimigo: [Array] }
  ]
}
```

E possuo uma função que modifica os participantes do `JSON` principal, retornando isto:

```
[
  {
    corredor: {
      id: 2,
      nome: 'Irmãos Rocha',
      velocidade: 7,
      drift: 4,
      aceleracao: 5,
      vantagem: 'MONTANHA'
    },
    aliado: [ 'Penélope Charmosa' ],
    imimigo: [ 'Peter Perfeito' ]
  }
]
[
  {
    corredor: {
      id: 5,
      nome: 'Barão Vermelho',
      velocidade: 7,
      drift: 3,
      aceleracao: 4,
      vantagem: 'MONTANHA'
    },
    aliado: [ 'Irmãos Rocha' ],
    imimigo: [ 'Professor Aéreo' ]
  }
]
{
  corredor: {
    id: 10,
    nome: 'Peter Perfeito',
    velocidade: 7,
    drift: 1,
    aceleracao: 2,
    vantagem: 'CIRCUITO'
  },
  aliado: [ 'Barão Vermelho' ],
  imimigo: [ 'Sargento Bombarda' ]
}
```

A questão é: como eu posso retornar um `JSON` novo com as mesmas propriedades do original (mantendo a pista, no caso), porém modificar somente os participantes, no caso substituindo os antigos pelos novos?
Já tentei algo assim:

```
novaCorrida = corrida.participantes.map(() => {
            return { ...corrida, participantes: novosParticipantesBuffados }
        })
```

Porém dessa forma ele retorna 3 participantes iguais.

Answer (score -3):

Como você já tem uma função que retorna um array de participantes, você poderia implementar a seguinte função:

```
const gerarNovoObj = (args) => (
  {
     ...corrida,
     participantes: gerarNovosParticipantes(args),
  }
);
```